# FBX from maya importing to Unity with wrong joint rotation

Tags: unity-game-engine, import, maya, fbx

I'm working on a project that needs to read the joint data from motion capture device to reconstruct the motion.
I already have a model in  MAYA where all the joint are having Y axis up-pointed. However, when I import that model to unity, many koints' rotation changed. I've tried different importing method including exporting a FBX then load to Unity and ecpoting to unity directly. I've also changed the default rotation in MAYA from XYZ to ZXY. But the problem still exists.
The mesh will twist since due to the wrong rotation as shown in the picture below. I've googled a lot but still not find a solution.
[error listed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6odzE.png)

Answer (score 0):

Usually the joint direction doesn't matter, though I used to set "z" instead "y" in my character rig.

Please go to your fbx import settings, choose your Rig/Animation Type as Humanoid. Then, create a new avatar Definition from this model.

You should now be able to remap your wrong or missing joints. It's most likely that you have wrong order of character joints' mapping.

Comment: Thank you for the information! I checked the mapping and I'm sure it's correct. Now I think it might be the problem of the motion capture device and I'm looking at it!